# The maths behind 'Sky and Water 1' by Escher

Tags: tessellations

I've been inspired by Eschers 'Sky and Water1' woodcut, his work is so mindblowing, it got me thinking whats the maths behind it. How did he do it?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at the following book: Contemporary Abstarct Algebra, by  J.A.Gallian

Comment: See M.C. Escher: Art and Science by H.S.M Coxeter